# android - standard way to ask the user the rate app and give the opportunity to share the app link with friends

Tags: android

I found different approaches to offer android app user the opportunity to share an app link with friends form within an app and also ask them to rate the app on google play. As I am a friend of doing things the standard way yet new to android I was wondering if there is a google recommended standard way to do this, to

- ask the user of an app from within the app to rate it on google play
- offer the opportunity to share a link to the app on google play from within the app via email, facebook etc with friends

Thanks buddies

**UPDATE**

As this was obviously not so clear, my question is mainly around the technical aspect of doing it. (other suggestions are of course also welcome)

**UPDATE 2**

Found

http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater

which is not exactly what I wanted but maybe useful for people stumbling over this thread. In its core it is what Budius suggested

Comment: thank you for update #2. Glad I stumbled over this thread and found that link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really not an 'standard' way of doing it. It's a very delicate situation, I guess the 1st rule will be don't be rude or over-intrusive to your users.

Leave the share option always available on some menu and don't force your users to use it.

About rating, you could count the amount of times your app is used (or for how long) and based  on that estimation pop a thing to give the user the option to rate it, but unless the user clicks "Remind me Later" do never show that message again.

**edit:**

based on the author comment:
nothing special code wise, to rate the app you just start an Action_VIEW to your app link (e.g. for my app)

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.budius.WiFiShoot")));
```

and for the share is the same standard share code ( http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html ) just passing your app link and maybe some extra message like : "check out my awesome app!"

Comment: Thanks Budius - I actually dont like these please rate the app popups myself so all I want to do is have a link for it in the about section of the app. My question was actually more about the technical aspect, what lib to use, what intent to call etc - do you think i should rephrase my question.

Comment: thanks for your answer which got me on the right track it seems ;-)